# How to measure collector current in BJT?

Tags: circuit-analysis, bjt

In the following circuit:

[image]

I know the expression for the collector current is $$I_C =\frac{V_{CC}-V_C}{R_L}$$
Say I have a potentiometer for \$R_L\$ and I decide to set it to 0 Ω. What would \$I_C\$ be in this case?

Comment: You should be able to quickly derive this active mode result:$$I_\text{C} = \frac{\beta}{\beta+1}\cdot \frac{V_\text{CC}\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}-V_\text{BE}}{R_\text{E}+\frac{R_1\cdot R_2}{\left(R_1+R_2\right)\cdot\left(\beta+1\right)}}$$ and take note of its independance of the collector resistor value.

Comment: By the way, you will know if the mode is actually active by using the above equation to compute the voltage drop across \$R_\text{L}\$. If it is excessively high and forces the collector voltage below the base voltage, then it's not in active mode and is instead in saturation and the above equation no longer holds.

Answer (score 3):

Let me show the voltages and collector current (I<sub>C</sub>).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3rPSb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As you can see, \$V_B = V_{BE} + V_E = V_{BE} + I_E \cdot R_E\$.

Since \$I_C \approx I_E\$, the equality above turns into \$V_B \approx V_{BE} + I_C \cdot R_E\$. Finally, $$I_C = \frac{V_B - V_{BE}}{R_E}$$
*(I will not show what VB is since it can be found with simply voltage divider rule.)*

See? Collector current is independent from collector load!

NOTE: Placing a resistor to emitter creates a constant current source. It also guarantees the thermal stability.

Answer (score -1):

Lets assume Beta = infinity. And assume the Ic is near 1mA, so the Vbe is approximately 0.6 volts (0.5 volts near 10uA, 0.4 volts near 100 nanoAmps).

Ic = (Vbase - 0.6) / Re

Where Vbase = VDD * the voltage divider ratio

thus Vbase = VDD * R2 / (R1 + R2)

and now, finally,

Ic = { [VCC * R2/(R1 + R2)] -  0.6} / RE

Again, assuming beta = infinity, Vbe = 0.6, and Vearly = infinity

With all 3 resistors being 1KOhm, and VCC = 3 volts, we have

Ratio = 0.5,

Vbase = 3*0.5 = 1.5 volts,

Vemitter = Vbase - 0.6 = 1.5 - 0.6 = 0.9 volts

Ic = 0.9 / 1K = 0.9 milliAmps